# how can i parse json object without using anu key

Tags: android, json

I want to parse data from the below type of json format.Anybody please help me.The problem is there is no key for get value from json object.eg: how can i get the value "America East Conference".Anybody please help me it is very important to me

```
 {
   "America East Conference":{
      "1":{
         "Team_id":"156",
         "Team_name":"UMBC Retrievers",
         "Sport_code":"AE",
         "Overall_wins":"4",
         "Overall_losses":"26",
         "Logo":"http:\/\/hoopla.sixsquaretechnologies.com\/logo_uploads\/UMBC Retrievers.png"
      },
      "2":{
         "Team_id":"7",
         "Team_name":"Albany Great Danes",
         "Sport_code":"AE",
         "Overall_wins":"24",
         "Overall_losses":"8",
         "Logo":"http:\/\/hoopla.sixsquaretechnologies.com\/logo_uploads\/Albany Great Danes.png"
      }
   },
   "American Athletic Conference":{
      "1":{
         "Team_id":"61",
         "Team_name":"Connecticut Huskies",
         "Sport_code":"AE",
         "Overall_wins":"20",
         "Overall_losses":"13",
         "Logo":"http:\/\/hoopla.sixsquaretechnologies.com\/logo_uploads\/Connecticut Huskies.png"
      },
      "2":{
         "Team_id":"52",
         "Team_name":"Cincinnati Bearcats",
         "Sport_code":"AE",
         "Overall_wins":"22",
         "Overall_losses":"10",
         "Logo":"http:\/\/hoopla.sixsquaretechnologies.com\/logo_uploads\/Cincinnati Bearcats.png"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject main = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject East = main.getJSONObject("America East Conference");

JSONObject one = East.getJSONObject("1");
String Team_id = one.getString("Team_id");
String Team_name = one.getString("Team_name");
String Sport_code = one.getString("Sport_code");
String Overall_wins = one.getString("Overall_wins");
String Overall_losses = one.getString("Overall_losses");

JSONObject two = East.getJSONObject("2");
String Team_id2 = two.getString("Team_id");
String Team_name2 = two.getString("Team_name");
String Sport_code2 = two.getString("Sport_code");
String Overall_wins2 = two.getString("Overall_wins");
String Overall_losses2 = two.getString("Overall_losses");

JSONObject Athletic = main.getJSONObject("America Athletic Conference");

JSONObject one3 = Athletic.getJSONObject("1");
String Team_id3 = one.getString("Team_id");
String Team_name3 = one.getString("Team_name");
String Sport_code3 = one.getString("Sport_code");
String Overall_wins3 = one.getString("Overall_wins");
String Overall_losses3 = one.getString("Overall_losses");

JSONObject two4 = Athletic.getJSONObject("2");
String Team_id24 = two.getString("Team_id");
String Team_name24 = two.getString("Team_name");
String Sport_code24 = two.getString("Sport_code");
String Overall_wins24 = two.getString("Overall_wins");
String Overall_losses24 = two.getString("Overall_losses");
```